# Compiler won't accept valid code? error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Tags: c, windows, xinput

Just want to start by saying thank you for taking the time to look at my problem.

Below is the code that is giving me the error:

```
// INFO(Tanner): XInputGetState Support
#define X_INPUT_GET_STATE(name) DWORD WINAPI name(DWORD dwUserIndex, XINPUT_STATE* pState);
typedef X_INPUT_GET_STATE(x_input_get_state);

X_INPUT_GET_STATE(XInputGetStateStub)
{
    return(ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_CONNECTED);
}
global_variable x_input_get_state* XInputGetState_ = XInputGetStateStub;
#define XInputGetState XInputGetState_


// INFO(Tanner): XInputSetState Support
#define X_INPUT_SET_STATE(name) DWORD WINAPI name(DWORD dwUserIndex, XINPUT_VIBRATION* pVibration);
typedef X_INPUT_SET_STATE(x_input_set_state);

X_INPUT_SET_STATE(XInputSetStateStub)
{
    return(0);
}
global_variable x_input_set_state* XInputSetState_ = XInputSetStateStub;
#define XInputSetState XInputSetState_
```

The problem accoring to the compiler is that I don't have the open currly brace "{" for my XInputGetStateStub and XInputSetStateStub.

Any help is appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will preprocess to the following:

```
typedef DWORD WINAPI x_input_get_state(DWORD dwUserIndex, XINPUT_STATE* pState);;

DWORD WINAPI XInputGetStateStub(DWORD dwUserIndex, XINPUT_STATE* pState);
{
    return(ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_CONNECTED);
}
global_variable x_input_get_state* XInputGetState_ = XInputGetStateStub;

typedef DWORD WINAPI x_input_set_state(DWORD dwUserIndex, XINPUT_VIBRATION* pVibration);;

DWORD WINAPI XInputSetStateStub(DWORD dwUserIndex, XINPUT_VIBRATION* pVibration);
{
    return(0);
}
global_variable x_input_set_state* XInputSetState_ = XInputSetStateStub;
```

As you can see there is an extra `;` after the `DWORD WINAPI XInputSetStateStub(DWORD dwUserIndex, XINPUT_VIBRATION* pVibration)` due to `#define` ending with a `;`. Remove that, and see if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you, I should probably go to bed now.  Missing that obvious of a mistake...twice, at least I got a lot of work done in the last 12 hours.

Thank you again.